# how to change capture_method in stripe for particular product in checkout woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

we have been using WooCommerce Stripe Gateway plugin.which provide capture method as manual or  automatic.But if it set any of one on admin,the selected option will be  apply for all product on checkout.   we need change change capture method for one category product to manual in checkout. is it possible with following filter

```
wc_stripe_payment_metadata
```

Answer (score 0):

the following filter worked .

```
add_filter( 'wc_stripe_generate_payment_request', 'change_cap',2,3 );
function change_cap( $post_data, $order, $prepared_source ) {
        $post_data['capture_method']='manual';
}
```